# Error in log with Fire and Forget API resource in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

According to [One-Way Messaging in a Fire-and-Forget Mode through ESB in WSO2 ESB Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+12%3A+One-Way+Messaging+in+a+Fire-and-Forget+Mode+through+ESB) I have the following resource:

```
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{serviceId}/*">
  <inSequence>
     <property name="CHANNEL_COD" value="999"/>
     <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
     <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
     <log>
        <property name="**** INSIDE" value="[API] /emma/{serviceId}"/>
     </log>
     <property name="serviceId" expression="get-property('uri.var.serviceId')"/>
     <log>
        <property name="**** SERVICE_VALUE" expression="get-property('serviceId')"/>
     </log>
     <switch source="get-property('serviceId')">
        <case regex="Servicio">
           <log>
              <property name="**** Servicio CASE" expression="get-property('serviceId')"/>
           </log>
        </case>
        <default>
           <log>
              <property name="**** Default CASE" expression="get-property('serviceId')"/>
           </log>
        </default>
     </switch>
     <send/>
  </inSequence>
```

But, when I look in SystemLog (from WSO2 Console) I can see two following error messages:

1. The system cannot infer the transport information from the /context/servicio URL.
2. Unexpected error during sending message out

The behavior is correct, but I don't know if I do wrong anything.

PD: It's a mock resource to trying Fire&Forget resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a send at the end of your inSequence. But without an endpoint definition and without initializing heater To, this send means "send back the response message to the caller".

However, there is no request and so no response and moreover, you define FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED that send back an ack (http status code 202)

Remove this send that make no sense (in the sample that you mention, there is an endpoint definition inside the send)